# NoPactsFoundException even there is a pact in the Pact Broker

Tags: java, testing, pact

There is definitely a pact available because I can see it in the Pact Broker.
But still when running the Pact Provider Test, it says it cannot find a Pact.
At the moment there is this error message:

> au.com.dius.pact.provider.junitsupport.loader.NoPactsFoundException: No Pact files were found to verify

So we have no clue what could be the reason. Also we are not using any selectors.

Comment: latest pact temporarily solved it. But wonder why Pact Broker not automatically get latest Pact

Comment: There are many reasons for this. Please explain your setup - including tags/branches on your consumer contract, and your provider setup that verifies the contract. I'd suggest logs also at debug level

Comment: In the plugin added in configuration  <branchName>${branch}</branchName> and in systemProperties of failsafe Plugin added <pactbroker.enablePending>true</pactbroker.enablePending>
<pactbroker.providerBranch>main</pactbroker.providerBranch>
<pact.provider.branch>${branch}</pact.provider.branch>
Then the PactNotFoundException came

Comment: @MatthewFellows could you please answer :)
By the way hard coded publishing as branch main the pact again could be found. *shrugging*